# Surviving icinga2 restart in a python requests stream

Tags: python, python-requests, icinga

I have been working on a chatbot interface to icinga2, and have not found a persistent way to survive the restart/reload of the icinga2 server. After a week of moving try/except blocks, using requests sessions, et al, it's time to reach out to the community.

Here is the current iteration of the request function:

```
    def i2api_request(url, headers={}, data={}, stream=False, *, auth=api_auth, ca=api_ca):
    ''' Do not call this function directly; it's a helper for the i2* command functions '''
# Adapted from http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/icinga2-api
# Section 11.10.3.1

    try:
        r = requests.post(url,
            headers=headers,
            auth=auth,
            data=json.dumps(data),
            verify=ca,
            stream=stream
            )
    except (requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError,requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError, http.client.IncompleteRead,ValueError) as drop:
        return("No connection to Icinga API")

    if r.status_code == 200:
        for line in r.iter_lines():
            try:
                if stream == True:
                    yield(json.loads(line.decode('utf-8')))
                else:
                    return(json.loads(line.decode('utf-8')))
            except:
                debug("Could not produce JSON from "+line)
                continue
    else:
        #r.raise_for_status()
        debug('Received a bad response from Icinga API: '+str(r.status_code))
        print('Icinga2 API connection lost.')
```

(The debug function just flags and prints the indicated error to the console.)

This code works fine handling events from the API and sending them to the chatbot, but if the icinga server is reloaded, as would be needed after adding a new server definition in /etc/icinga2..., the listener crashes.

Here is the error response I get when the server is restarted:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 447, in _update_chunk_length
    self.chunk_left = int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 228, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 498, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 451, in _update_chunk_length
    raise httplib.IncompleteRead(line)
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 664, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 349, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 526, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 246, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/errbot/plugins/icinga2bot.py", line 186, in report_events
    for line in queue:
  File "/home/errbot/plugins/icinga2bot.py", line 158, in i2events
    for line in queue:
  File "/home/errbot/plugins/icinga2bot.py", line 98, in i2api_request
    for line in r.iter_lines():
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 706, in iter_lines
    for chunk in self.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size, decode_unicode=decode_unicode):
  File "/home/errbot/err3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 667, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

With Icinga2.4, this crash happened every time the server was restarted. I thought the problem had gone away after we upgraded to 2.5, but it now appears to have turned into a heisenbug.

Comment: So you tried to catch a ValueError? That causes all your subsequent errors

Comment: The ValueError was a fallback position but a red herring because I wasn't catching at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up getting advice on IRC to reorder the try/except blocks and make sure they were in the right places. Here's the working result.

```
def i2api_request(url, headers={}, data={}, stream=False, *, auth=api_auth, ca=api_ca):
    ''' Do not call this function directly; it's a helper for the i2* command functions '''
# Adapted from http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/icinga2-api
# Section 11.10.3.1

    debug(url)
    debug(headers)
    debug(data)

    try:
        r = requests.post(url,
        headers=headers,
        auth=auth,
        data=json.dumps(data),
        verify=ca,
        stream=stream
        )
        debug("Connecting to Icinga server")
        debug(r)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            try:
                for line in r.iter_lines():
                    debug('in i2api_request: '+str(line))
                    try:
                        if stream == True:
                            yield(json.loads(line.decode('utf-8')))
                        else:
                            return(json.loads(line.decode('utf-8')))
                    except:
                        debug("Could not produce JSON from "+line)
                        return("Could not produce JSON from "+line)
            except (requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError,ConnectionRefusedError):
                return("Connection to Icinga lost.")
        else:
            debug('Received a bad response from Icinga API: '+str(r.status_code))
            print('Icinga2 API connection lost.')
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
    requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError) as drop:
        debug("No connection to Icinga API. Error received: "+str(drop))
        sleep(5)
        return("No connection to Icinga API.")
```